# How to kill something once it's 'slid' off screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a script that uses jquery slide to move two items (text/video and background randomly drawn from a database) to the right and replace them with a new ones that comes in from the left:

```
        if (clickType === 0) {
            $("#image_link_1,#image_text_1") .hide("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1250);
            $("#image_link,#image_text") .show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1250);
            clickType = 1;
        } else if (clickType === 1) {
            $("#image_link,#image_text") .hide("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1250);
            $("#image_link_1,#image_text_1") .show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1250);
            clickType = 0;
        }
    }).each(function() {
        if (this.complete)
            $(this).load();
    });
}
;
```

However videos 'pushed' off page that have autoplay enabled begin playing even though they aren't visible

How do I go about killing them once they're off screen?

Many thanks

Comment: may they be deleted or do you just want them to be disabled?

Answer (score 2):

Call a `remove` from the callback:

```
$("#image_link_1,#image_text_1") .hide("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1250, function() {
    $(this).remove(); 
});
```

Add this to the other `hide` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery `.remove()` function to remove/destory a selected element on the page.

More information on the remove function:
http://api.jquery.com/remove/

To define the element you want to remove you'd use:

`$(".class").remove();`

or

`$("#id").remove();`

You could always use one of the many other jQuery selector types too.

**EDIT**

You can also remove it using the callback. This will remove the element once the slide is completed.

```
$("#image_link,#image_text") .hide("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1250, function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: This is true, but you should call it in the callback from hide, so it executes when the slide is complete. Like this: `$("#image_link_1,#image_text_1") .hide("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1250, function() { $(this).remove(); }).remove);`

Answer (score 0):

With fire.

Use `$('#selector').remove()` to delete items from the DOM permanently.